# Python + JSON Formatting ('list' object has no attribute 'values')

Tags: python, json, string, list, dictionary

I'm getting the following error. I'm confident the error is due to my JSON formatting. How should I be formatting my JSON file?

```
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'list' object has no attribute 'values'
```

The error is occurring on the following line

```
total_sites = len(custom_sites.values())
```

The function it's trying to execute

```
def get_available_websites():
    string = []
    with open('settings.json') as available_file:
        for sites in json.load(available_file)['custom_sites']:
            string.append(sites + ", ")
    return (''.join(string))[:-2]
```

The JSON file

```
{
    "custom_sites": [
        "https://github.com",
        "https://test.com"
    ]
}
```

I've tried various changes in the JSON file. Alternating [], and {}

Comment: where are you defining the variable `custom_sites`?

Comment: `custom_sites = json.load(json_file)['custom_sites']`
Just above the `total_sites = len(custom_sites.values())` line

Answer (score 0):

`custom_sites` will be a list not a dict so it wont have a values attribute. you can just check the length of the list its self.

```py
import json

json_str = """{
    "custom_sites": [
        "https://github.com",
        "https://test.com"
    ]
}"""

custom_sites = json.loads(json_str)["custom_sites"]
total_sites = len(custom_sites)
print(f"{total_sites=}")
```

**OUTPUT**

```
total_sites=2
```

Comment: how should i format my json file to work with what i originally posted?